# VMWare - Ubuntu Install Error

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

When I Run Ubuntu 64-bit Machine ( From Boot Disc ) 
And After A Purple Ubuntu Loading Screen
Some Codes Come Up With Bunch Of Errors

Some Of The Errors :

```
 end_request: I/O error,dev sr1, sector
 SQASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failder to read block
 SQASHFS error: Unable to read page, block
```

and some other SQASHFS errors

After a Long time Of Erroring , 13 `end_request: I/O error,dev sr1, sector` errors will show and then nothing ... ubuntu will stuck at there

What is wrong ? i think is something like permission error how i fix this ?

Thanks,

Comment: The error seems to suggest that there is some problem to read from the device sr1. If it is a defect of the booting disk you have to fix there... maybe check if the disk is correctly done, dirty... and eventually try with a new one.

Comment: I tried to copy disk contents to my pc but at 'filesystem.squashfs' the coping operation stucked ... And also i tried to clean disk but didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those errors are fairly generic and may be indicitive of multiple types of issues.

1. **Your boot media may be corrupt** - On the initial screen of the Ubuntu installer, you can 'Check disc for defects'. Make sure that passes.

   If you cannot get that far, download a fresh copy of the Ubuntu OS ISO that you want to use, and try using that. If you're using a burned CD/DVD, try burning a new copy on a slower burn setting and check the 'verify media' post-step, if available. You can also try using a [bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
2. **Incompatible ACPI** - If that does not help, another issue may be an incompatible ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) on the host system. You can disable this before the Ubuntu install starts by pressing **F6** and going into Other Options:

   From Ubuntu BootOptions > [Changing the CD's Default Boot Options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)

   > **F6** Other Options. ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) and EDD (Enhanced Disk Drive) options which may help if your computer does not support or has problems with these systems. Highlight the selection and press the ENTER key or SPACE key to select it. An "X" will appear, indicating selection. Multiple items can be selected from this popup menu. Hit ESC to leave the popup menu. The selections are retained at the time the user presses the ESC key.

   Select the option **`acpi=off`** and see if you can proceed with the installation.

   [image]

Comment: I fixed it already , but thanks anyway , and my boot files was corrupted, i downloaded Ubuntu 16 iso and installed it and worked perfectly